# If i release a coin from its upright position and it falls sideways on a frictionless surface, will it rotate around the $x$-axis?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Frictionless surface

$$I_0 = Icm + MD^2.$$

Also, if it does, the coin will fall down thus changing the cm. Will this affect the inertia? or must i use parallel axis theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a coin starts on an edge and falls over on a friction-less surface, the center of mass must go straight down. Notice that a vector perpendicular to the surface goes from horizontal to vertical. There is rotation. The motion is complex, but the energy [mgh + (1/2)m$v^2$ + (1/2)I$ω^2$] is conserved until it hits the surface. (Each term refers to the center of mass.)

Comment: can i just check what is the inertia? is it the usual 0.5mr^2?

Comment: The relevant, I, would be for an axis through the center of mass and parallel to the flat surface of the coin. (Not a simple integral.)